# Adding Children in StackLayout using Binding in ViewModel, Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

I am trying to implement MVVM in my Xamarin.Forms project.

This is my `StackLayout` with x:Name

```
<StackLayout x:Name="approvalsStack"></StackLayout>
```

And This is how I am populating `Children` in this `StackLayout`

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();
                    Frame frame = new Frame { BorderColor = Color.LightGray };
                    frame.Content = new Label { Text = a.FullName + " (" + a.Decision + ")" + " " + a.DecisionDate.ToString() };
                    stack.Children.Add(frame);
                    approvalsStack.Children.Add(stack);
```

Now I am stuck, How can I populate the children using ViewModel/Binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it in that way, as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout-1.children?view=xamarin-forms), Property `Children` in `StackLayout` is not a [Bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties).

However you can **solve** that by making custom one with implementation of bindable-property which will have some `ItemSource` for dynamically adding/removing items from it, or you can just use some great community implementations of `RepeaterView` for Xamarin.Forms, which I recommend you to do.

`RepeaterView` is basically a Bindable `StackLayout` where you can populate items dynamically.

I recommend you to take a look at this one [here](https://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/09/24/xamarin-forms-repeaterview/) from *[Glenn Versweyveld](https://twitter.com/depechie)*, if you want you can search on google or on github for some more additional ones *(but I strongly recommend you this one)*.

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: Yes i think i should use RepeaterView.. Will feed you back after implementation.Thanks

Comment: Ok, let me know if you are ok with it.

Comment: Thanks Bro.. Helped Alot :)

Comment: Nice to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

Found the Solution!!

https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Xamarin-Forms-RepeaterView/blob/master/Repeater/Repeater/RepeaterView.cs

1-Used this implementation of RepeaterView
2-Added Namespace to Xaml

```
<local:RepeaterView x:Name="approvalsStack" ItemsSource="{Binding Approvals}">
                        <local:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Decision}"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DecisionDate}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:RepeaterView>
```

and Bound the repeater view then poplulated it with ViewModel